# ReactJS fetch data from custom API and render data

Tags: json, reactjs

I am currently working on a ReactJS project where I created my own JSON-api.  I am trying to fetch a specific value in the array but all I get back is `undefined`, `console.log` gives me this: [Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxY4s.png).

My fetch function is as follows:

```
_fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/stories');
  const json = await response.json();

  this.setState({
    title: json.title,
    thumbnail_img_url: json.thumbnail_img_url
  });
}
```

Comment: why no using axios?

Answer (score 0):

Please learn basic programming first.

> gives me this: Array.

You yourself said `json` is an array and trying to access its property with `json.title`. Please either use the first element of the array or revisit your flow and see what you actually want to do.

```
_fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/stories');
    const json = await response.json();

    this.setState({
      title: json[0].title,
      thumbnail_img_url: json[0].thumbnail_img_url
    });
  catch (err) { console.error(err.toString()); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that very constructive comment.  Whereas the rest of your answer was thoroughly helpful, cudos!